# Cauchy problem: $x'=\frac{x}{t^2+1}, x(0)=1$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant, cauchy-problem

> $$x'=\frac{x}{1+t^2}, \qquad x(0)=1$$

I know the solution to the problem, but I don't get to the right solution myself. My solution:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$$

$$\ln(x)=\cot(t)+ C$$

$$\ln(1)=\cot(0) + C$$

$$e=C$$

$$\ln(x)=\cot(t) + e.$$

I don't know how to solve the problem further. I think that the constant also is incorrect, because the solution is given as $x=e^{\operatorname{arccot}(t)},\; t \in \mathbb{R}$. Can someone assist with the problem?

Comment: We can also write $$x(t)=c_1e^{\arctan(t)}$$

Comment: $\int \frac{dt}{1+t^2}$ is $\arctan t$, not $\cot t$.

Comment: Lots of students (1) are taught to write $\tan^{-1}$ rather than $\arctan,$  and (2) never learn trigonometry very well, to say the least. Consequently when you mention "arctangent" to a class of calculus students, often someone asks "Is arctangent the same as cotangent?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not far from the solution. But you are being a bit sloppy in the notation, as well as having the wrong antiderivative. First let's rewrite
$$\frac{x'}{x}=\frac{1}{1+t^2}.$$
Now, taking the integral **over $t$** in both sides gives:
$$\int \frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}\,dt=\int \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt $$

$$\ln(x(t))=\arctan(t)+c$$

$$x(t)=e^{\arctan(t)+c}$$

And finally, using $x(0)=1$ gives $c=0$.

---

As @mathcounterexamples kindly pointed out, one should actually write

$$\ln(|x(t)|)=\arctan(t)+c$$
from which
$$|x(t)|=e^{\arctan(t)+c}.$$
and lastly, since $x(0)=1$, $c=0$ and for $x(t)$ to be continuous, $x(t)=e^{\arctan(t)}$

Comment: More generally, you have $\ln \vert x(t) \vert=\arctan(t)+c$ rather than  $\ln(x(t))=\arctan(t)+c$. However, I agree with your final solution as $x(0) = 1 >0$.

Comment: @b00nheT Thank you for the answer, but can you explain how is $x'(t)dt$ integrated? And also, do we get the possible values for t from the first expression?

Comment: Try differentiating $\ln(f(t))$ with respect to $t$ using the chain rule. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you are indeed right. I tried adressing the problem in my edit, but am not too happy with my answer. Please feel free to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

$$ x = e^f $$

Then:

$$ (e^f)' = \frac{e^f}{1+t^2} $$

$$ f'e^f = \frac{e^f}{1+t^2} $$

$$ f' = \frac{1}{1+t^2} $$

$$ f = arctan(t) +f(0) $$

$$ x = e^{arctan(t)+f(0)} $$

$$ f(0) = ln(x(0)) = ln(1) = 0 $$

Solution:

$$ x = e^{arctan(t)} $$